# Using MongoDB and PHP To Do Full Text Search

Tags: php, mongodb, search, mongodb-query

I am trying to use MongoDB and PHP to create a full text search of my database. There is a title attribute and a body attribute. So, for example, a sample entry would look something like this:

```
{ title : 'University of Maine', body: 'A university located in the state of Maine.'}
```

The current code that I am using only returns a match if the search term is matches something in the title:

```
$results = $this->database->find(['text' => ['$search' => $search_word]]);
```

I would like it to also return results for search terms that **also** match the body. So for example if I had another entry:

```
{title: 'Steven King', body: 'A famous author who attended the University of Maine.'}
```

And my search term was 'University of Maine', these two entries would be returned. The current code that i have (above) will only return 'University of Maine'. How do I modify my current find to also search the body attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is allow text search on all field in your document. To do that need to create a [wildcard text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes):

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

Then your query will returns all documents that contains the given string. You can also control the [search results with weights](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/).

The syntax to create the index with PHP driver is:

```
$collection->createIndex(array('$**' => 'text'));
```

Comment: where would I add the index and how would it look in PHP?

Comment: create index on your collections. You will need to drop existing text indexes